# Rendering a React Native Image Dynamically in a map function with external links

Tags: image, react-native

```
let result = this.state.yards.map( yard=> {
         return <View><Text style={{color:'black'}}><Text style= 
{{color:'darkslateblue', fontSize:18}}>{yard.name}</Text>{"\n"}{yard.coordinates}  {yard.photourl}</Text><Image source={require(yard.photourl)} /></View>
      });
```

yard.photourl represents the correct url that works in the browser but I can't seem to dynamically render this in a this.state.items.map

The links are public aws links.

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the React Native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images), network images are loaded with the following syntax:

`<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />`

Note that you need to manually specify the image size.